# Sending Message from Service to Activity

Tags: android, android-service, android-handler

I have a Service and i try to send message to my primary Activity just like this:

```
public void callAsynchronousTask() {
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Message m = new Message();
                        m.arg1 = 10;
                        m.arg2 = 15;
                        handler.sendMessage(m);
                        Log.i("Sent", "!");

                    } catch (Exception e) {}
                }
            });
        }

};
timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 0, 3000); 
}
```

How can i fetch this message data in my Activity ?

Answer (score 2):

In your activity, you should make a handler like this, and pass the reference to the handler to the service before you start it...

```
handler = new Handler() {
  @Override
  public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
    //msg.arg1
  }
};
```

but right now you are creating a handler inside the service but thats not what you wanted to do!

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be to bind your Activity to your Service so that they can communicate.

Reference
[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#bindService(android.content.Intent, android.content.ServiceConnection, int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#bindService%28android.content.Intent,%20android.content.ServiceConnection,%20int%29)

Comment: My question is how to fetch data from a sent message

Comment: Moreso you should be trying to figure out a better way to have your Activity communicate with your service.

Comment: Jox's approach is what you want here. Read about [Bound Services here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html) - you'll see that you can provide a callback method which in your instance can expose a ````getArgs(Integer...)```` method or better. +1

Answer (score 0):

put your data in `message.obj` and take it from this field in your activity. Your data can be a class that you can define how you want it.

Comment: I need the code in my Activity, my problem is to receive the data, not to send it.

Comment: make your activity to implement  Handler.Callback and put your code in method public boolean onMessage(Message message)

Answer (score 0):

There is [simple example](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Service/Downloader)  project  (which is created by [CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware)) which  shows how to send messages from `Service` to `Activity` via `Handler`. Check it out

Answer (score 0):

```
        //use this code to send data to activity

         Bundle data = new Bundle();
            data.putString("data", result);
            Message msg = Message.obtain();
            msg.setData(data);
            replyTo.sendMessage(msg);        //replyTo is handler declared in your main_Activity 






    //Pass this **replyTo** handler when you call your service from mainActivity..
          Handler replyTo= new Handler() {
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            //get data here and do what you want..
        };
        };
```

Hope it helps..!